# Package shared object (library) with Python Egg / Wheel

Tags: python, shared-libraries, setuptools

I've done this so far:

1. Created `MANIFEST.in` with: `include path/to/libfoo.so`
2. Created `setup.py` that after calling `setupt.py install` puts the `libfoo.so` into `/usr/local/lib/python/site-packages/foo.egg/path/to/libfoo.so`.

This, of course, doesn't help Python to find `libfoo` when it's required at run time.  What do I need to do to make Python actually find this library?

#### Note

This library doesn't have Python bindings, it's just a shared library with some native code in it.  It is called from another shared library which sits in `/usr/local/lib/python/site-packages/foo.egg/path/wrapped.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hard-code the location of shared library, you can use the `rpath` option.  For that you would do something like..

```
python setup.py build_ext --rpath=/usr/local/lib/python/site-packages/foo.egg/path/to
```

Where the setup.py above is the script used to build `wrapped.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and the `rpath` is the path to `libfoo.so`  Of course you should be able to put this directly inside the build script, depending on what that process looks like.

> -rpath=dir
>
> Add a directory to the runtime library search path. This is used when
>   linking an ELF executable with shared objects. All -rpath arguments
>   are concatenated and passed to the runtime linker, which uses them to
>   locate shared objects at runtime. The -rpath option is also used when
>   locating shared objects which are needed by shared objects explicitly
>   included in the link

If it's not an option to update the build process for `wrapped.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` I think your only option it to put `libfoo.so` somewhere that's in the load library path or manually add the location at run-time.

In answer to a few of your follow-on questions...

The system load library locations come from `/etc/ld.so.conf` and references the locations in the `ld.so.conf.d` directory.  The `ldconfig` command rebuilds the the cache for shared libraries from this data so if you change things be sure to call this command.

At the command line or in your `.bashrc` you can use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=....` to add additional directories to the search path.

You can manually load shared objects.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html *Loading shared libraries*.

I haven't tried this myself but I've read that if you manually load a subordinate shared library in your python code and then import the higher level library, the linker won't have to go out and find the lower one since it's already loaded.  This would look something like...

```
import ctypes
foolib = ctypes.CDLL('/full/path/to/libfoo.so')
import wrapped
```

There's a number of examples on StackOverflow on how to do this and lots of additional info/examples on manipulating the library search paths.

Comment: This is great info and helps me a lot, but I still have questions: what is the default value of runtime library search path? It would be easier for me to arrange it so that libraries are in the default location than try to change this setting. (2) I tried putting the library in the place `ld` can find it: this didn't help Python in finding it. (3) How would I load it manually? I looked into `wrapped.py` generated by Cthon, but it's too cryptic / I'm not sure what exactly does it do.

Comment: Answers to the above questions added to the original answer.

Comment: I think I should say, it looks like maybe the solutions here are getting more complicated than they need to be.  Take a look at an installed python project that has multiple shared libraries in it.  Look at the `__init__.py` file and you can get some examples of loading subcomponents that might work for you.

Comment: In the end, I figured that the problem was the specific linker, which, when creating shared libraries also encoded the search path into the library being linked to into the library being compiled, and this is why putting the shared object in, say, `/usr/lib` didn't work. In the end, I kind of made it work by hardcoding the desired library location and having the setup script move it there. This, of course, makes it not cross-platform and not installable in custom locations... (contd)

Comment: The documentation of `setuptools` is really bad and even if it's possible to somehow write the setup script to be more generic, it certainly never mentions that. As for the "other projects and their `__init__.py` - I've done that... it's a terrible mess, which works only sometimes. Most Python projects that require extra shared libraries with them don't work on Windows, or with `pip`, or with `pip --user` or with different `setup.py install` options... It's a really bad infrastructure planning...